# How to stick custom post at the top in search results

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, search, sticky-post

I'm trying to stick a post in the search results for the value and meta_key meta_value. If the search results in the post is meta_key - sticky and meta_value - fatured, the display on top of these posts.
This is my search.php :

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if (is_paged()) $is_paged = true; ?>

<div class="wrapper" >
    <div class="clearfix container_border">

        </div>

    <?php
    $is_search = 0;
    global $wpdb;
    $totalpost_count = 0;
    $all_pids = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT group_concat(ID) FROM $wpdb->posts where post_status='publish'");
    $all_pids_arr = explode(',',$all_pids);
    if($_REQUEST['srch_location'])
    {
        $is_search = 1;
        $srch_location = $_REQUEST['srch_location'];
        //$location_pids = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT group_concat(tr.object_id) FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt join $wpdb->term_relationships tr on tr.term_taxonomy_id=tt.term_taxonomy_id where tt.term_id=\"$srch_location\"");
        $location_pids = $wpdb->get_var("select group_concat(post_id) from $wpdb->postmeta where meta_key like 'add_location' and meta_value like \"$srch_location\"");
        $location_pids_arr = explode(',',$location_pids);
        $all_pids_arr = array_intersect($all_pids_arr,$location_pids_arr);
    }


    if($is_search && !$all_pids_arr)
    {
        $all_pids_arr[0] = 'nopost';
    }
    if($_REQUEST['srch_property_id'])
    {
        $post_ids_str = $_REQUEST['srch_property_id'];
        $sub_cat_sql .= " and p.ID in ($post_ids_str) ";
    }else
    {
        if($all_pids_arr)
        {
            $post_ids_str = implode(',',$all_pids_arr);
            if($post_ids_str)
            {
                $sub_cat_sql .= " and p.ID in ($post_ids_str) ";
            }
        }   
    }
    $featurecat = get_cat_id_from_name(get_option('ptthemes_featuredcategory'));
    if($featurecat)
    {
        $srch_feature_pids = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT group_concat(tr.object_id) FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt join $wpdb->term_relationships tr on tr.term_taxonomy_id=tt.term_taxonomy_id where tt.term_id in ($featurecat)");
        $srch_feature_pids = '';
    }
    $blogcat = get_cat_id_from_name(get_option('ptthemes_blogcategory'));
    $blogcatcatids = get_sub_categories($blogcat,'string');
    if($blogcatcatids)
    {
        $srch_blog_pids = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT group_concat(tr.object_id) FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt join $wpdb->term_relationships tr on tr.term_taxonomy_id=tt.term_taxonomy_id where tt.term_id in ($blogcatcatids)");
    }
    if($srch_blog_pids && $srch_feature_pids)
    {
        $sub_cat_sql .= " and p.ID not in ($srch_blog_pids,$srch_feature_pids) ";
    }elseif($srch_blog_pids && $srch_feature_pids=='')
    {
        $sub_cat_sql .= " and p.ID not in ($srch_blog_pids) ";
    }elseif($srch_blog_pids=='' && $srch_feature_pids)
    {
        $sub_cat_sql .= " and p.ID not in ($srch_feature_pids) ";
    }
    $srch_sql = "select p.* from $wpdb->posts p $post_meta_join where p.post_status='publish' and p.post_type='post'  $sub_cat_sql";
    if($srch_feature_pids)
    {
        $feature_srch_sql = "select p.* from $wpdb->posts p where p.post_status='publish' and p.post_type='post' and p.ID in ($srch_feature_pids)";
        $srch_sql = " select * from (($feature_srch_sql) union ($srch_sql))";
    }

    $totalpost_count = $wpdb->get_var("select count(p.ID) from $wpdb->posts p $post_meta_join where p.post_status='publish' and p.post_type='post'  $sub_cat_sql");
    global $posts_per_page,$paged;
    if($paged==''){$paged=1;}
    $startlimit = $posts_per_page*($paged-1);
    $srch_sql .= "  order by p.ID desc limit $startlimit , $posts_per_page";
    $post_info = $wpdb->get_results($srch_sql);

    ?> 



   <div class="contentarea">


    <h5>
    <?php
    if($_REQUEST['s'] == 'viewmore')
    {
        _e(LATEST_PROPERTIES_TEXT);
    }
    elseif(is_category() && $_REQUEST['search']=='')
    {
        echo single_cat_title();
    }else
    {
        //echo __(SEARCH_TEXT). get_search_param();
        echo get_search_param();
    }   
    ?></h5>     
    <?php if($post_info) { ?>

    <ul class="display ">
    <?php
    $count=0;
    foreach($post_info as $post_info_obj)
    {
        $count++;
        $post = $post_info_obj;
        get_property_info_li($post);
        if($count%3==0)
        {
        ?>
        <li class="blank"></li>
        <?php   
        }
    }
    ?>
    </ul>
    <?php
        }else
        {
            _e(NO_PROPERTY_AVAILABLE_MSG);
            if($_POST['search']=='search')
            {
                echo get_search_param();
            }
        }
        ?>
    <?php if($post_info) { ?>
    <div class="pagination">
         <?php if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { ?><?php wp_pagenavi(); ?><?php } ?>
     </div>
    <?php }?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple hack. Edit: putting the featured post ids in an array and checking that array in the main loop.

```
global $post;
$post_IDs = array();
foreach($post_info as $post_info_obj) {
    $post_IDs[] = $post_info_obj->ID;        
}

$featured_IDs = array();
$query1 = new WP_Query(array('meta_key'=>'sticky','meta_value'=>'featured','post__in'=>$post_IDs));

while($query1->have_posts()) {
    $query1->the_post();
    $featured_IDs[] = $post->ID;
    get_property_info_li($post);
}
```

First thing do to in the main loop: if the post is featured, skip it.

```
if(in_array($post_info_obj->ID,$featured_IDs)) { continue; }
```

Comment: Nor would you add to this code Do_not_duplicate in search results ?

Comment: Yeah, I made a small edit to avoid duplicates.